# Reading data from a Firebase Realtime Database and sorting it by value - iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, sorting

I am very new to iOS development and the Swift language so please explain it to me like I'm 5 :)
I have an online database [Image of the database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i04fM.png) here.
I want to read these key:value pairs from the database and sort them into an order of highest to lowest key value pairs sorted by their value. This would be a high scores page for the game I am developing.

So far I have been able to retrieve the data from the database by doing this: [how I am obtaining the data from the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBzJb.png). I am then able to sort the data using this: [Sorting the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU9O9.png). This is the output currently: [Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D56uK.png).
My problem is that after I have this sorted dictionary of key:value pairs I can't find a way to get the sorted data and shove it into an array to then print it out later in a high score table format.
Here is the total code block that I am working with: [the code I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TQrd.png)

Comment: Hello! On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of code.  Copy the code into the question itself and use the editor to format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. Please edit the question to do so.

Comment: I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and after that visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and please also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for helping me to realize that I need to work on my question asking. This was my first post and I see all of the points you are making. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you can convert your sorted dictionary to an array:

```
let arr = usersAndScoresDictionary.map { "\($0.key) \($0.value)" }
```

You can do this for any of your dictionary, for example, if you only wanted the values of the dictionary and not the keys. I am assuming your keys are equal to 0, 1, 2, ...